# Ajax response in json Parsing error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to update a table with JS/Ajax.

My Ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://192.168.122.104:8001/controllers/updateList.php?',
  data: "query=" + query + "&" + zpeaktype + "year=" + pickedyear,
  dataType: 'html',
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
  cache: false,
  success: function(response)
  {
        $("#current_picked_year").html("&nbsp;"+pickedyear);
        alert(response[184]+""+response[185]+""+response[186]+""+response[187]+""+response[188]);
        var ajaxdata = JSON.parse(response);

        $(".table-event").find("#eventnamefield").text(ajaxdata.lang);
});
```

When my Ajax request is done, the error is the following :

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 186 of the JSON data"

My JSON data (returned by PHP script) :

```
{"language":"breton","organizer":"zpeaktest","eventname":"A vos mousses","eventtype":"party","eventdayname":"Mardi","eventdaynumber":"26","eventmonthname":"juillet","eventtime":"14:30"},{"language":"autre","organizer":"demozpeak","eventname":"Aperotest","eventtype":"party","eventdayname":"Samedi","eventdaynumber":"30","eventmonthname":"juillet","eventtime":"20:30"},{"language":"autre","organizer":"demozpeak","eventname":"March\u00e9 des lices","eventtype":"party","eventdayname":"Lundi","eventdaynumber":"15","eventmonthname":"ao\u00fbt","eventtime":"12:45"}
```

Maybe (I supposed), it could be the ":"  character of "12:45" for example,  but I don't know how to escape it...

EDIT : Thanks,  In other ajax scripts,  I iterate on array adding some commas,  but finally I don't need here.

Before :

```
$lastevent = end($events);
foreach ($events as $event) {
  if ($event == $lastevent) {
    echo json_encode($event);
  } else {
    echo json_encode($event).", ";
  }
```

Finally, that's sufficient :

```
  echo json_encode($events);
```

I don't have the error anymore, but I'm asking what is recommended as contentType / dataType  AJAX  (when sending the request)  ?

Comment: It's telling you the where the error is column 186... which is at `"},{"` in your json data. That doesn't seem to be valid json. You are sending 2 json responses separated by a comma.

Comment: use   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: @Bindrid that is not the appropriate property to change

Comment: @Bindrid you are confusing `contentType` and `dataType`. They are not the same thing

Comment: Opps, wrong direction. thanks

Comment: Show how you send this data in php. The problem is there. Run that through a json validator and you will see it is invalid json

Comment: DataType is html instead of "json"

Comment: Yes,  dataType is html when request is sent, but if I change to json (or contentType too),  I got similar errors (it doesn't understand the JSON).

Comment: You can only echo json ***once per ajax request***. You can't echo individual objects in a loop. End result is invalid json client side